# Installing maven2 without openjdk

Tags: ubuntu, maven-2, java

by default ubuntu comes with openjdk. I installed jdk from sun, and removed openjdk, but with openjdk I had to remove maven2. How can I reinstall it without installing openjdk?

```
~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)

~$ sudo apt-get install maven2
(...)
The following extra packages will be installed:
(...)
openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless
  openjdk-6-jre-lib
(...)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
(...)
openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless
  openjdk-6-jre-lib
```

Any help appreciated, I have googled a lot and I haven't found any solution :/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can simply download tar.gz archive from Maven [web-site](http://maven.apache.org/download.html) and unpack it to some directory like this (will unpack it to /opt):

```
tar -xzvf apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz -C /opt
```

After it you need to set `$M2_HOME` variable:

```
export M2_HOME=<path_to_maven>
```

And add it to `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

To check you can launch:

```
mvn -version
```

Note:
If it does not work for all the terminals.
Performed the below steps.
Become superuser.

Fire below commands.

```
nano /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

Paste the below lines.

`export M2_HOME=<path_to_maven>`

`export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin`

`ctrl +O` to save and `ctrl +X` to exit.

Fire the below commands.

```
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/maven.sh

source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh

mvn -version
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks! To other noobs like me, though, just make sure that `<path_to_maven>` doesn't include a trailing `/`. this made my path variable look like `...:/opt/apache-maven-3.0.4//bin:...`, and stuff didn't work until I fixed that.

Comment: Just for completeness, the 2 lines setting the `$M2_HOME` and `$PATH` environment variables can be put in a file named `/etc/profile.d/maven.sh` and they will be executed (for all users) when the user logs into ubuntu. So, the `mvn` command will be available for you after you log out and log in again without the need to do the `export` thing again each time.

Comment: Thanks.  In addition I used `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mvn mvn /opt/apache-maven-3.2.3/bin/mvn 1` to set up the link to `/usr/bin/mvn`.

Answer (score 7):

For me this command solved the same problem fast:

`sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install maven`

Comment: I'm afraid it will download openjdk when `apt-get update` is called and there is new version of maven available

Comment: Might be worth noting this installs maven3.. It's a subtle change from the OP's question.

Comment: yes, my goal was maven3, and it was ok for me, may be we can change it to "sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install maven2"

Comment: `The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bsh ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless junit4
  libaether-java libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbatik-java
  libcdi-api-java libdoxia-java libfop-java
  libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java libmaven-scm-java libmaven2-core-java
  libplexus-bsh-factory-java libplexus-containers1.5-java libsisu-ioc-java
  libwagon-java libwagon2-java maven openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless`

Comment: Indeed, It downloads the openjdk 11. For those whoe have fired the command. Here is the command to remove it.

`sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk*`
`sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`

Comment: @Varun You cannot just drop openjdk that way, since that will drop standard maven package depending on it

Answer (score 0):

Generally for Google Compute Engine, AWS or Cloud below commands will be useful

```
sudo wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz

sudo tar -xzvf apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz -C /var/lib/

sudo vi /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

Add below lines to the file

> export M2_HOME=/var/lib/apache-maven-3.3.9
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin

Save the file and close editor . Then execute below command to exit the connection or console and relogin

```
exit
```

Once reconnected or login, execute below command to check maven version

```
mvn -version
```