# Trying to compile mahout but getting error - Cannot execute mojo: resources. Build is not using pom.xml

Tags: maven, mahout

I have completed the following steps:

1. Installed Java 1.6
2. I am using Ubuntu 11.10. Added the $JAVA_HOME path in /etc/bash.bachrc
3. Installed maven. `mvn --version` is showing the installed maven correctly.
4. Downloaded Mahout from `http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk`

Now, I go inside mahout/trunk and try to do `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean install -X -e`, then it gives the follwoing error -

> Cannot execute mojo: resources. It requires a project with an existing
>   pom.xml, but the build is not using one.

I just want to try the examples in the mahout/examples. How to fix this error?

**There is a pom.xml in the directory.**

Full terminal output is here:

```
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-6)
Java version: 1.6.0_23
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.0.0-16-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
[DEBUG] Building Maven user-level plugin registry from: '/home/kartikeya/.m2/plugin-registry.xml'
[DEBUG] Building Maven global-level plugin registry from: '/usr/share/maven2/conf/plugin-registry.xml'
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Wagons could not be registered as the extension container was never created
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:12 for project: null:maven-clean-plugin:maven-plugin:2.3 from the repository.
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:9 for project: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:12 from the repository.
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache:apache:pom:4 for project: org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:9 from the repository.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Cannot execute mojo: clean. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Cannot execute mojo: clean. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot execute mojo: clean. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 21 11:32:36 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/55M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you verify there is a pom.xml in the directory where you are running "mvn clean install"?

Comment: Yes there is a pom.xml in that directory.

Comment: install the newest maven 3.0.4, remove all files from ~/.m2 (or move to other location) and try again. It works for me

Comment: Works for me too. This error really means there is not a valid pom.xml in your dir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you ajozwik and Owen.

I installed maven2 from the aptitude. I took the following steps to fix this issue:

1. Removed Maven2 `sudo apt-get remove maven2`
2. Installed Maven 3.0.4 for ubuntu as directed in - [Installing maven2 without openjdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518523/installing-maven2-without-openjdk)
3. Even after doing this, I got the error -

   `Unable to locate the javac Compiler in:[ERROR] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/tools.jar`

To fix this, JDK needs to be reinstalled. It worked for me!. For those even, if this solution doesn't work, please have a look at - [Why maven ignores my JAVA_HOME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350722/why-maven-ignores-my-java-home)

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

"Cannot execute mojo: resources. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml"

This error means there is not pom.xml in the working directory